# Add Azure Service Bus Rules via HTTP

Tags: c#, rest, azure, nservicebus

I am changing the way my code receives messages from an Azure Service Bus Subscription.

Previously I was using the SDK classes and now I am changing to http REST calls.

In order to create a rule for a subscription and set a filter on this rule, I always receive http 400 as a return.

It seems the way I am creating the body is not correct:

```
            var rule = $"https://{serviceBusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{topicPath}/subscriptions/{subscriptionName}/rules/{ruleName}";

            var content = new StringContent(@"<RuleDescription xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect"">
             < Filter i: type = ""SqlFilter"" >
              < SqlExpression > type = 'REPLY' AND username = 'blabla@contoso.com' </ SqlExpression >
             </ Filter >
            </ RuleDescription >
            ", Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

            var requestResponse = await _httpClient.PutAsync(rule, content, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
```

I am also setting the following headers:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", _token);
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/atom+xml");
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/atom+xml");
```

Any ideas about what is missing?

Comment: Do you have any update about this SO thread? If it is useful, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Hi. I am still working on that. Soon I will give more updates/mark as answer. Thank you.

Comment: If have any confusion about it,  please let me know.

Comment: Thing is I am still using the classic API approach, so I have something stable and can think about using the management API in the next improvement.
For now I am stuck with the SqlFilter for the rule, where no matter what I do I receive all messages, where I should receive only the ones that are on the filter criteria...

Comment: It seems it is another issue, you could accept it to close this SO thread. And you could post another SO thread to add more detail information to descript it. If I have free time I will look into that and you also could get the help from other communities.

Comment: The issue with the rule filter was not actually an issue. Accordingly to this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639437/sqlfilter-on-azure-servicebus-topic-subscription-not-filtering/11659401#11659401), when you create a subscription a filter that "accepts everything" is created automatically. So all I had to do was to delete it after subscription creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error information it means that request parameters error. I am not familar with mentioned api, you could share the link if possible.

But I recommand that you could use the [Rules - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/rules/createorupdate). It is easy for us to use. For more information about service bus api, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/).

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{namespaceName}/topics/{topicName}/subscriptions/{subscriptionName}/rules/{ruleName}?api-version=2017-04-01
```

I also do a demo for it.

1) Get the access token

```
private static async Task<string> GetToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string secretKey)
        {
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);
            var tokenResponse = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential);
            var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
            return accessToken;
        }
```

2) About how to get the tenantId ,clientId and secret key please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application). And don't forget assign to role the application.

```
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "clientId";
var secretkey = "sercret Key";
var subscriptionId = "subscription Id";
var resurceGroup = "resourceGroup";
var nameSpace = "servicebus namespace";
var topicName = "topicName";
var subscription = "service subscription name";
var ruleName = "rule name";
var token = GetToken(tenantId,clientId,secretkey).Result;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add( new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   var body = "{\"properties\": { \"filterType\": \"SqlFilter\"},\"sqlExpression\": { \"sqlExpression\": \"myproperty=test\"}}";
   HttpContent content = new StringContent(body);
   var url = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resurceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{nameSpace}/topics/{topicName}/subscriptions/{subscription}/rules/{ruleName}?api-version=2017-04-01";
   var response = httpClient.PutAsync(url, content).Result;
 }
```

**Test result**

[image]

**Update**:

> It seems the way I am creating the body is not correct:

Yes, you are right. According to your mentioned [API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/hh780755%28v%3Dazure.100%29), we could know the body is xml format. But you xml code string is not xml format, you could vaild with xml validator online. There should be no space between charater `<`/ `>` and tags. For example  `< Filter i: type = ""SqlFilter"">` should be `<Filter i: type = ""SqlFilter"">`

But it is a classic rest api.

> We’re no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service, technology, or API is supported.

I recommand that you could use the Azure manmagement API, we also could get access token with [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#service-to-service-access-token-request).

```
public static string GenerateAccessToken(string resource, string tenantId, string clientId,string secretKey)
        {
            var url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token";
            var body = $"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={secretKey}&resource={resource}";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
            };
            StringContent content = new StringContent(body);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
            var json = JObject.Parse (result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            return json["access_token"].ToString();
        }
```

If you still want to use the [classic api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/hh780755%28v%3Dazure.100%29), I also do a demo. please hava a try with following code.

1.Get sastoken code

```
public static string GetSasToken(string resourceUri, string keyName, string key, TimeSpan ttl)
  {
         var expiry = GetExpiry(ttl);
         string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
         HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
         var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
         var sasToken = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}",
         HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, keyName);
         return sasToken;
 }

private static string GetExpiry(TimeSpan ttl)
{
  TimeSpan expirySinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + ttl;
   return Convert.ToString((int)expirySinceEpoch.TotalSeconds);
 }
```

2.Create a rule with  c# code.

```
var serviceBusNamespace = "serviceBusNameSpace";
var topicPath = "topicPath";
var subscriptionName = "subscription name";
var ruleName = "testrule2"; // rule name
var sharedAccessKeyName = "xxxSharedAccessKey",
var key = "xxxxxxM2Xf8uTRcphtbY=";
var queueUrl = $"https://{serviceBusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{topicPath}/subscriptions/{subscriptionName}/rules/{ruleName}";
var token = GetSasToken(queueUrl, sharedAccessKeyName,key ,TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
            var body = @"<entry xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"">
   <content type =""application/xml"" >
   <RuleDescription xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect"">
           <Filter i:type=""SqlFilter"">
               <SqlExpression> type = 'REPLY' AND username = 'blabla@contoso.com' </SqlExpression>
             </Filter>
           </RuleDescription>
         </content>
       </entry>";
            var length = body.Length.ToString();
            var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
            var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/atom+xml");
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/atom+xml");
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", length);
            var requestResponse =  _httpClient.PutAsync(queueUrl, content, new System.Threading.CancellationToken()).Result;
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: The sample code does not work for me. For creating the access token I need some class libraries not supported by .NET 4.0 (my target .net framework version).
The API I am using can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/hh780755%28v%3dazure.100%29
I am creating the token and already using to make some service-bus related operations, like send and receive messages. My problem now is to setup the SQL filter.

Comment: The API I am trying to use contains information on how to create a new rule. using is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/hh780774(v%3dazure.100)

The body of the request should be created like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/hh780755%28v%3dazure.100%29

I believe my problem is to create the body request.

Comment: `I believe my problem is to create the body request`. Yes you are right. The body string of the xml is not well format. I update the answer with demo xml string. And I also add the way to get access token **without** .net library. I see that you are using classic API. I recommand that you could use the [Azure management API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/hh780774(v%3dazure.100)).